# Importação de classe que fica cinza

Tags: android, android-studio

Quando importa uma classe que não está sendo utilizado, ela fica cinza e imediatamente é apagada. Como faço para ela não ser apagada automaticamente.

Estou usando Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa desativar o **Auto import** do seu *Android Studio*. Para isso:

1) Vá em **Preferences**

2) Em **Editor** > **General** , selecione **Auto Import**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Deixe apenas a primeira opção selecionada, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê **Ok** ou **Apply** para que a configuração seja salva.

Comment: Me perdoe se esta duvida for um tanto noob, mas onde encontro a opção Preferences?

Comment: Se estiver usando Windows: `Ctrl+Alt+S`. Caso esteja usando OSX : `CMD + ,`